# Ripgrep Missing Character Class + Repetitions

Tags: regex, ripgrep

Why do these match:

```
echo 'CCAGCTACTCGGGAGGCTGAGGCTGGAGGATCGCTTGAGTCCAGGAGTTC' | grep -E 'CCAGCTACTCGGGAGGCTGAGGCTGGAGGATCGCTTGAGTCCAGGAG[ATCG]{2}C'
echo 'CCAGCTACTCGGGAGGCTGAGGCTGGAGGATCGCTTGAGTCCAGGAGTTC' | rg 'CCAGCTACTCGGGAGGCTGAGGCTGGAGGATCGCTTGAGTCCAGGAG[ATCG]{1,2}C'
echo 'CCAGCTACTCGGGAGGCTGAGGCTGGAGGATCGCTTGAGTCCAGGAGTTC' | rg 'CCAGCTACTCGGGAGGCTGAGGCTGGAGGATCGCTTGAGTCCAGGAG[ATCG]{2,}C'
echo 'CCAGCTACTCGGGAGGCTGAGGCTGGAGGATCGCTTGAGTCCAGGAGTTC' | awk '$0 ~ /CCAGCTACTCGGGAGGCTGAGGCTGGAGGATCGCTTGAGTCCAGGAG[ATCG]{2}C/'
```

But this does not:

```
echo 'CCAGCTACTCGGGAGGCTGAGGCTGGAGGATCGCTTGAGTCCAGGAGTTC' | rg 'CCAGCTACTCGGGAGGCTGAGGCTGGAGGATCGCTTGAGTCCAGGAG[ATCG]{2}C'
```

I was under the impression that ripgrep used rust regex engine, which should be able to handle the character class + repetition?

Comment: Looks like a bug in rg. Did you report it?

Comment: Yup, this is a bug. I filed an issue for you: https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep/issues/1319

Comment: Thanks guys! This was literally the first thing I tried with ripgrep, so I just assumed I was wrong and rg was right.

Comment: It [looks to be fixed on Feb 17](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep/issues/1319).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it identified a good bug in an implementation that has now been fixed.  Others are not likely to run into this issue again.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to a bug ([issue 1319](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep/issues/1319)) in ripgrep which was fixed in version `12.0.0`.